# Get all the nodes in the system

Tags: nodes

I've found [node_load_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) which allows me to get all the nodes, but I need to specify some parameters, e.g. the type of node that I'd like to fetch.

I'd like to get all the nodes in the system without the criteria. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [`entity_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7)

```
$nodes = entity_load('node');
```

If you don't provide the second argument (`$ids`) it will load up all entities of the given type:

> $ids: An array of entity IDs, or FALSE to load all entities.

Just for the sake of completeness `node_load_multiple()` doesn't require the `$conditions` parameter so you could also grab all of the node ids from the database

```
$nids = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node}')->fetchCol();
```

And then use `$nids` to load the nodes:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

Comment: MrFluff asked how to load all nodes of specific type, not all nodes at all

Comment: @Eugene admittedly it's a bit confusing but the question was actually _I'd like to get all the notes in the system without the criteria. How can I do that?_ so he's looking for all nodes, not just those of a specific type

Comment: As i understand "Notes" are not "Nodes" - this is custom content type.

Comment: @EugeneFidelin I think we can safely assume he meant 'nodes', as the answer has been accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `node_load_multiple(FALSE)`, and you will get all the nodes present in the site.

Keep in mind that it returns all the nodes, and this would be a problem when there are many nodes: The function takes time to be executed, and each node uses memory to be stored. With enough nodes, you would exhaust all the available memory.

Using the [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class, you can limit the number of returned nodes.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  // It returns the first 10 nodes.
  // Use range(10, 10) to get the next 10 nodes.
  ->range(0, 10);  

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($result['node']));
}
```

I added `propertyCondition('status', 1)` because you are normally interested on published nodes; if you want to get all the nodes, remove that line.

Notice that the `$conditions` parameter for [node_load_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) is not anymore used in Drupal 8. If you need to get some nodes basing on some conditions, you should use the `EntityFieldQuery` class.

#### References

- [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to find all node ids in your website.

```
$nids = array_values(\Drupal::entityQuery('node')->execute());
```